# Минимальная ОС для сервера

Tags: память, веб-сервер, сервер

Нужна операционка для веб-сервера с минимально возможными требованиями по памяти. Сервер будет запущен в учебном заведении, там непонятно какие, но гарантированно небольшие ресурсы будут.

Comment: Что значит минимально возможными? Windows 2000 server, несмотря на якобы прожорливость винды к ресурсам, успешно крутилась на PII 233MHz/RAM 64mb, одновременно обслуживая до 20 подключений. У меня сейчас FreeBSD8 на PIII 800MHz/RAM 512mb работает шлюзом, файл-сервером и джаббер-сервером на 108 машин, при этом несильно напрягаясь. Не жмитесь, ставьте то, что вам  удобнее, а там уже увидите реальную нагрузку и поймете, куда вам двигаться дальше.

Answer (score 3):

[nanoBSD](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/NanoBSD), а также всевозможные разновидности Linux, оптимизированные для встраиваемых решений.

Answer (score 2):

Поскольку являюсь сторонником CentOS рекомендую ее самую.При установке выбор конфигурации шикарный

Answer (score 1):

Gentoo Linux, FreeBSD

Answer (score 1):

лично я предпочитаю убунту сервер. Идет без иксов, зато с встроенными пакетами для ссш, веб и прочего.

Answer (score 1):

убунту и никаких вопросов

Answer (score 0):

только debian. там все из коробочки и ничего лишнего